# context menu Items in leaflet

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet, neshan

I'm making a map using the `Neshan` platform.
I want to show context menu of a marker،
I have written this code but it's not displaying the context menu

```
myMap.on('click', function (e) {
    marker = new L.Marker(e.latlng, {
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuItems: [
            {
                text: 'Marker item',
                index: 0
            }, 
            {
                separator: true,
                index: 1
            }
        ]
    }).addTo(myMap);
});
```